# Unable to find network card after executing mdev - s?

Tags: linux, kernel, module

I am customizing a Linux system with a Linux kernel version of 6.4.0. I executed `mdev -s` in `rcS` and checked the startup print, which was also successful. When I entered the live environment, I saw that the name of the network card was `enp2s0`. However, after startup, I found that `enp2s0` could not be found. I don't know what's going on? I have checked the kernel configuration and found that the network driver is compiled.

rcS:

```
echo PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib:/lib:/lib64

mount -a

source /etc/profile

mkdir /dev/pts -p

mount -t devpts devpts /dev/pts

mdev -s
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "mdev -s executed successfully."
else
    echo "mdev -s execution failed."
fi
ip addr add 192.168.5.2/24 dev enp2s0
```

Screenshot of error reporting:

[image]

Comment: hey, you're posting a new question every 3.5 hours. Does that mean your previous questions are already solved? In that case, please post an answer to the (or delete them, but preferably answer them).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry, mainly because I am learning to customize Linux systems and am a beginner, so I have many problems. In my opinion, my previous problem was only temporarily evaded or ignored. After searching for similar issues, I think my problem has not been truly resolved, so I did not reply or delete it.

Comment: so, friendly advice: solve problems, one after the other. Having 20 open problems is not good.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for your advice. I will pay attention to the rhythm and way I ask questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved because the network card driver is incorrect. First, enter the live environment, execute `lspci | grep -i ethernet` to see what model of your network card is, and then compile it into the kernel.

```
Device Drivers->Network device support->Ethernet driver support->(the model of your network card)
```